# Should I use __restrict on references?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, reference, restrict-qualifier

In the program I am coding, one of my function declarations goes like this:

```
bool parse( const sentence & __restrict sentence )
{
  // whatever
}
```

When I compile the code with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express, the compiler complains:

> warning C4227: anachronism used : qualifiers on reference are ignored

However, [this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html) of GCC’s documentation says:

> In addition to allowing restricted pointers, you can specify restricted references, which indicate that the reference is not aliased in the local context.

And the same page gives a very explicit example:

```
 void fn (int *__restrict__ rptr, int &__restrict__ rref)
 {
   /* ... */
 }
```

Did I misunderstand MVSC’s warning? or should I transform all my references into pointers so that `__restrict` applies?

Comment: What's the point of comparing MSVC and GCC here? `__restrict` is a **vendor extension**, so you have to play by each vendor's rules.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++ has no notion of `restrict` in the way C99 does.

However, several compiler vendors offer extensions to their C++ compilers, which they call `__restrict` (note the reserved name!). Given that those are *extensions*, their behaviour is determined by the com­pi­ler vendor. You will have to read the documentation and find out what this extension does in each com­pi­ler separately.

Just because two vendors chose the same name doesn't mean the extensions have anything in common.

Comment: Can you give an example of where two extensions have the same name but different meaning for different compilers?

Comment: @RafaelSpring: Sure. In the DS9K compiler, every name starting with double underscores has a different meaning during every compilation run :-)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably since it starts with `__` `__restrict` is an implementation-specific extension that can behave as each implementation desires. I imagine both compilers are correct in this case.

Instead of changing your references to pointers, why not avoid `restrict` entirely, instead using a profiler to find your hot spots, and only if it shows that such aliasing not covered by the C++ strict-alias rules is taking significant CPU time would I consider changing one specific reference to a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

**Generally, you should.** (But probably not in the function in question).

It's true that C++ doesn't have a `restrict` keyword, so one could argue you "can't" use it. But we all know that `restrict` is useful and even important for optimizing code, especially code that doesn't get inlined; and you should definitely indicate that different pointers in your code can't alias, if they can't alias. People often implicitly assume non-aliasing without `restrict`'ing their pointers.

But do allow for lack of compiler support. For example, and for G++/clang only:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
// great, __restrict__ is available
#else
// too bad, can't use __restrict__
#define __restrict__ 
#endif

int foo(int* __restrict__ a, int* __restrict__ b);
```

Now, you might be thinking: "Ah, but I was asking about a reference!" - well... a reference parameter to a function is mostly a pointer with cute syntax. Sure, it's not the same thing, and there's lifetime extension rules, and rvalue references and what-not, but still.

Finally in your function specifically, it seems like `sentence` is the only pointer (unless you get other pointers from elsewhere in the function body). When that's the case, you needn't bother `restrict`ing it, since there's nothing for it to alias.