# C++ restrict Semantics

Tags: c++, restrict, restrict-qualifier

I'm in the process of updating performance critical libraries to use restrict, as implemented in C++11 by g++ and MSVC with the keyword `__restrict`.  This seems to be the most-standard-extension, so I'll use `restrict` and `__restrict` interchangeably.

`restrict` is a C99 keyword, but nevertheless compilers have defined important uses for it in C++.

This post intends to be a "question" asking about what each C++-specific use is and what it means, followed by a CW answer answering it.  Feel free to add/check/edit.  So: "Help!  What do these C++ uses of the `restrict` keyword mean?"

1. Qualifying `this` (restrict a method):

   ```
   void Foo::method(int*__restrict a) __restrict { /*...*/ }
   ```
2. Restrict a reference:

   ```
   int&__restrict x = /*...*/;
   ```
3. Restrict inside a template:

   ```
   std::vector<float*__restrict> x;
   ```
4. Restrict a member/field.  This technically also applies to C's `struct`,  but it comes up as an issue in C++ more often than it does in C:

   ```
   class Foo final { public: int*__restrict field; };
   ```

Comment: This could easily have been four good, to-the-point, questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Qualifying `this` (restrict a method):

   This means that the `this` pointer is restricted.  This one major consequence:

   - The method can't operate on itself as data, e.g.:

     ```
     void Foo::method(Foo*__restrict other) __restrict { /*...*/ }
     ```

     In that example, `this` might otherwise alias `other`.  `restrict` is saying that you can't call this method with itself as an argument.
   - Note: it is *okay* to access or change the object, even through a field.  The reason why is that the following are functionally identical:

     ```
     void Foo::method1(void) __restrict { field=6; }
     void Foo::method2(void) __restrict { this->field=6; }
     ```

     In that example, `this` is not aliased with anything.
2. Restrict a reference:

   It appears to mean exactly that--that the reference is restricted.  What this exactly *does* and whether it's useful is another matter.  Someone on [this thread](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/569075-__restrict-on-c-references/) claims compilers can statically determine aliasing for references, and so the keyword is supposedly useless.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841279/should-i-use-restrict-on-references) was also asked about whether it should be used, but the answer "vendor specific" is hardly helpful.
3. 
4. There is precedent on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307190/restrict-keyword-and-pointers-inside-structs).  In short, in function `f`, the compiler knows that `a.field` and `b.field` are not aliased:

   ```
   class Foo final {
       int*__restrict field;
   };
   int f(Foo a, Foo b) { /*...*/ }
   ```

   This will often be the case, assuming `a!=b`--for example, if field is allocated and destroyed by the constructor/destructor of Foo.  Note that if field is a raw array, it will always be true and so the `restrict` keyword is unnecessary ([and impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929162/restrict-in-g-and-msvc-with-array-syntax)) to apply.

Comment: About field-restriction - is it not a restriction vis-a-vis _any_ pointer to _anything_ in a scope which uses a Foo? I mean, if it's not limited to the same instance, why would it be limited to fields of the same class?

Comment: @einpoklum Yes; I think you are correct; I would now (8ish years later) expect that the rule is something like "`__restrict` is a promise to the compiler that any compatible pointers in scope don't alias". That is, if we have `int*__restrict` `Foo::field` and some random bare `int*__restrict`, if they're in the same scope, the compiler treats them as unaliased.