# What are exact rules for dealing with pointer aliasing in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

In C there is `restrict` keyword which tells the compiler that there is no aliasing between pointer arguments of a function, allowing it this way to perform some optimizations which otherwise will not be allowed. For example:

```
void add(int* restrict ptrA,
         int* restrict ptrB,
         int* restrict val)
{
    *ptrA += *val;
    *ptrB += *val;
}
```

Now the instructions in function body can be executed in parallel because there is not aliasing between `val` and some of the `ptr` arguments. In C++ there is no `restrict` keyword.

1. What are exact rules for dealing of pointer aliasing in C++ defined by the standard?
2. What are popular compilers extensions which provide semantic similar to `restrict` in C? For example for **MSVC**, **g++**, **clang++** and **Intel C++ compiler**.
3. Is there any plans `restrict` keyword to be standardized in the future C++ standards?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940978/c-restrict-semantics

Comment: See this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict - "C++ does not have standard support for restrict, but many compilers have equivalents that usually work in both C++ and C, such as the GNU Compiler Collection's and Clang's __restrict__, and Visual C++'s __restrict and __declspec(restrict)."

Comment: (1) alone is a very large question.

Comment: Also see [How to avoid aliasing and improve performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31601142/1708801)

Comment: I'd say this question should be split up in order for someone to attempt an answer. I wouldn't mind hearing about where restrict standardization stands, I haven't read about it in years.

Comment: Potential dupe, in the sense that it gives a partial answer to (1.) and (2.): [What does the `restrict` keyword mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/776283/1593077).